# Date format with Google Drive REST API

Tags: php, rest, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm retrieving the "modifiedDate" attribute of a File through a GET request with the Google Drive REST API but I just can't figure out the date format.

Google's documentation states the date format is RFC3339 but when I do the following in PHP :

```
// The value I retrieve is "2014-11-20T13:34:19.139Z"
$date = \Datetime::createFromFormat(\Datetime::RFC3339, [value]);
```

PHP throws an error saying it couldn't create a date with this format and this value.

Do you know what is the actual date format used by Google in its REST API ?

Thanks for your answers.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the "dirty" solution I've implemented : upon receiving the date, I preg replace the pattern "/.[\d]{3}/" (removing the milliseconds) and then I'm good to go to create a date from the format RFC3339.

So instead of :

```
// The value I retrieve is "2014-11-20T13:34:19.139Z"
$date = \Datetime::createFromFormat(\Datetime::RFC3339, [value]);
```

I do :

```
// The value I retrieve is "2014-11-20T13:34:19.139Z"
$date = \Datetime::createFromFormat(\Datetime::RFC3339, preg_replace('/\.[\d]{3}/', '', [value]);
```